# Error in if (is.character(txt) && length(txt) == 1 && nchar(txt, type = "bytes") < : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, json

I am facing the above problem while running the following codes. I have installed the following packages:-

**Geocoding: OpenStreetMap API Search Functions:**

```
# INPUT LOCATION VARIABLES
# [RECORD_ID], [ADDRESS], [CITY], [STATE], [ZIPCODE]

geocode <- function(record_id, address, city, state, zipcode){
  
  # NOMINATIM SEARCH API URL
  src_url <- "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?q="
  
  ### INPUTS PREPARATION ###
  
  city <- str_replace_all(string = city, 
                          pattern = "\\s|,", 
                          replacement = "+")
  
  # CREATE A FULL ADDRESS
  addr <- paste(address, city, state, zipcode, sep = "%2C")
  
  # CREATE A SEARCH URL BASED ON NOMINATIM API TO RETURN GEOJSON
  requests <- paste0(src_url, addr, "&format=geojson")
  
  # ITERATE OVER THE URLS AND MAKE REQUEST TO THE SEARCH API
  for (i in 1:length(requests)) {
    
    # MAKE HTML REQUEST TO API AND TRANSFORM HTML RESPONSE TO JSON
    response <- read_html(requests[i]) %>%
      html_node("p") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      fromJSON()
    
    # FROM THE RESPONSE EXTRACT LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE COORDINATES
    lon <- response$features$geometry$coordinates[[1]][1]
    lat <- response$features$geometry$coordinates[[1]][2]
    
    # CREATE A COORDINATES DATAFRAME
    if (i == 1) {
      loc <- tibble(record_id = record_id[i],
                    address = str_replace_all(addr[i], "%2C", ","),
                    latitude = lat, longitude = lon)
    }else{
      df <- tibble(record_id = record_id[i],
                    address = str_replace_all(addr[i], "%2C", ","),
                    latitude = lat, longitude = lon)
      loc <- bind_rows(loc, df)
    }
  }
  return(loc)
}
```

**Data Collection: OpenStreeMaps API Request**

```
df <- geocode(record_id = bldg_df$record_id,
              address = query,
              city = bldg_df$city,
              state = bldg_df$state,
              zipcode = bldg_df$zipcode) 

head(df)
```

While running the above cell I am getting the following error:

```
Error in if (is.character(txt) && length(txt) == 1 && nchar(txt, type = "bytes") < : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
3.
fromJSON(.)
2.
read_html(requests[i]) %>% html_node("p") %>% html_text() %>% fromJSON()
1.
geocode(record_id = bldg_df$record_id, address = query, city = bldg_df$city, state = bldg_df$state, zipcode = bldg_df$zipcode)
```

Making the code minimal as possible:

```
geocode <- function(record_id, address, city, state, zipcode){
  src_url <- "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?q="
  city <- str_replace_all(string = city, 
                          pattern = "\\s|,", 
                          replacement = "+")
  addr <- paste(address, city, state, zipcode, sep = "%2C")
  requests <- paste0(src_url, addr, "&format=geojson")
  for (i in 1:length(requests)) {
    response <- read_html(requests[i]) %>%
      html_node("p") %>%
      q<- html_text()
  }
  return(q)
} 

q
```

Removed the `JSON()` and stored the `html_text()` to a variable q. Got the following response:

```
function (save = "default", status = 0, runLast = TRUE) 
.Internal(quit(save, status, runLast))
<bytecode: 0x0000022acf675480>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: That is a huge amount of code. Please reduce it and post a [mcve] instead.

Comment: Agree with @KonradRudolph. Having said that, I think what's happening here is that your `response` in the `geocode()` function is not returning the expected value. What is the value of `requests[i]` at the time you run this? If you visit that html page manually, does it look as you expect? By the time it goes rom `read_html()` through `html_node()` and `html_text()` and arrives at `fromJSON()`, it is `NA`. If you write big loops like this you need some error handling for when the result is not as expected.

Comment: Reduced the code logic. The html page is working perfectly fine.  I have added <if (TRUE && i == 1)> in place. Yet is persisting.

Comment: Thanks, that’s indeed already a drastic reduction but it’s still nowhere near the minimal code. From the error message it appears that the error happens in the call to `fromJSON()`. So you should store the result of `html_text()` inside a variable before passing it to `fromJSON()`. Then you can inspect that value and create a minimal example using just that value. See also: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1968).

Comment: Made the minimal code as above.